# Access Adminer on CentOS with Apache web server and Tomcat installed

Tags: apache-http-server, centos-7, tomcat

I have a VPS running CentOS 7. I got it a month ago to run a website for a local club. I have had quite some issues with getting it running, but after a few days finally everything worked. What I did:

- Installed Apache web server.
- Installed MySQL.
- Installed phpMyAdmin (which I couldn't get to work so I tried Adminer, which worked right away).
- Added my tables and data to the database.
- Switched to Tomcat, deployed the `.war`, and the website has been running fine since then.

Now I have to do some big updates on the database; so I stopped Tomcat, started `httpd`... and I can't get a connection anymore.

I see neither the Apache homepage when just typing the IP, nor do I see Adminer, which makes sense I guess because of the first point.

I remember having lots of trouble with `iptables` and `firewalld` and reading at least a hundred Stack Overflow and Super User questions about it, where the answers are always different. But at one point I had it working and since then the website ran fine, so I don't know why it's not working anymore.

At one point I also redirected port 80 to 8080, so users would not need to put 8080 in the address bar to access the website, but I don't know if that is the problem. Normally, my Tomcat runs on port 8080 and Aapache on 9080.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and sorry if this sounds like a load of noobness, but I really don't have a lot of experience with the command line. And if any crucial info is missing, just tell me!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So have you tried e.g. `localhost:8080` (and/or `localhost:9080`)?

Comment: How exactly would I test that via SSH? just ping that address?